# Summarize the number of non-numeric items using another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with several columns which are of type character and then a numeric column the aim is to summarize the character columns using the numeric column.

This is easier to explain using some example data and desired outcome. I have a feeling there's a nice solution in `dplyr`. I tried `ifelse` statements but couldn't get that to work.

Example data

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6), Cat1 = c("item1","item1","item1","item1",NA,"item1",NA,NA,"item1",NA,NA,"item1"),cat2 = c(NA,NA,NA,"item2","item2","item2",NA,NA,NA,NA,"item2","item2"))
```

df

```
   time  Cat1  cat2
1     1 item1  <NA>
2     1 item1  <NA>
3     1 item1  <NA>
4     1 item1 item2
5     2  <NA> item2
6     2 item1 item2
7     3  <NA>  <NA>
8     4  <NA>  <NA>
9     5 item1  <NA>
10    6  <NA>  <NA>
11    6  <NA> item2
12    6 item1 item2
```

Desired output:

| Category | No.of 1s | No of 2s | No.of others |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat1 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| Cat2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: @ekoam Thanks for pointing that out, I have made some edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape to 'long' format on the 'Cat' columns with `pivot_longer`, then `replace` the 'time' column where values are not 1, or 2 to
'others', get the frequency `count` and reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Cat"), names_to = 'Category', 
      values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(time = str_c('No_of_', replace(time, !time %in% c(1, 2), 'others')) )%>% 
  count(Category, time) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = n)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Category No_of_1 No_of_2 No_of_others
  <chr>      <int>   <int>        <int>
1 Cat1           4       1            2
2 cat2           1       2            2
```

Comment: If I wished to adjust my table to include any combination e.g. not just 1 and 2 but maybe 1,3,6 how would I do that?

Comment: @cgvoller i don't understand your comment.  The solution I provided matches with your expected updatd

Comment: @cgvoller i guess I undderstand what you meant.  Instead of `> 2`, you can use `%in%` with `!` in the updated

Comment: much appreciated for the explanation and help!